# Custom Activity - How to get InArgument in Validate endpoint

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity

I am developing a custom activity and I want to get the InArgument and eventDefinitionKey in /validate endpoint :
[image]

The req.body have just some properties here:

[image]

So, Can anyone let me know how can I get that data in validate endpoint ?
Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: maybe try `console.log(req)` to check what is in the payload, should be stored in req.data

Comment: Thanks for your answer but req.data is undefined and I don't see any things useful from req except req.body. I have an idea to use interactionId to get Journey data through SF Rest API. But I have a lot of organizations and there is no information to specify the organization in validate endpoint.